# Python ElementTree myroot.findall()

Tags: python, elementtree

I'm working with a XML file with Python ElementTree.
My file is like that :

```
<a expr="bla" para="1"/>
<a expr="bla" para="1">
  <b expr="bli" para="2"/>
<a exp="bla" para="1"/>
...
```

I want to print expr, no matters if it's a or b.
It should be like that :

```
expr = "bla"
expr = "bla"
expr = "bli"
expr = "bla"
```

I wrote this code :

```
for type_tag in myroot.findall('a'):
    expression = type_tag.get('expr')
    print("expr = ", expression)
```

but I don't know how to improve it to have the b too, at the right position.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Comment: A few tweaks would make this runnable code. Make it easy for us!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update the match expression to search the subtree (`.//`) for all elements (`*`) with the `expr` attribute (`[@expr]`).

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''
<root>
<a expr="bla" para="1"/>
<a expr="bla" para="1">
  <b expr="bli" para="2"/>
</a>
<a exp="bla" para="1"/>
</root>
'''
myroot = ET.fromstring(xml)

for e in myroot.findall(".//*[@expr]"):
    print(e.attrib['expr'])
```

Comment: This idea is better than me.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA - yours is very close and lots of `ElementTree` examples on the net do it your way. XPATH as used by `lxml` or the xpath-y stuff done by ElementTree is complicated stuff and the examples tend to dodge that. People parsing xml / html would do well to study xpath and use the lxml xpath method. Its very powerful if somewhat crazy.

Comment: Yes,I watch the document right now.I don't know much about how to use ``lxml`` module.I only use it when I use selenium.